# Typescript import statements not working in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, jasmine-node

I have a project written in `Typescript` which uses `jasmine-ts` to run a series of tests. 
I need to create a `Docker` container to run the tests for a few reasons.

Whilst the project locally runs OK `npm test`:

```
c:\github\gareththegeek\corewar>npm test

> corewar@0.0.26 test c:\github\gareththegeek\corewar
> nyc jasmine-ts

Started
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................


503 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.893 seconds
```

When I containerise the same folder and run `npm test` from the docker image, the Typescript imports don't seem to be recognised.

```
c:\github\gareththegeek\corewar>docker run corewar

> corewar@0.0.26 test /usr/src/app
> nyc jasmine-ts


/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307
        throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
              ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
parser/Expression.ts (1,29): Cannot find module './interface/IExpression'. (2307)
parser/Expression.ts (2,39): Cannot find module './interface/IToken'. (2307)
parser/Expression.ts (3,30): Cannot find module './interface/ITokenStream'. (230
```

My docker image is as basic as it comes:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

I'm really unsure why the docker container behaves differently to my local `npm test` command. I'm going to assume it's because locally I'm on windows and the docker container isn't. But I'm really unsure how to debug this.

Can anyone give any pointers on why Typescript imports aren't working within docker the way I'm expecting them too? 
I can paste over some of the Typescript code if it's any help.

Answer (score 3):

*Sigh* ignore this question, I resolve the issue by realising that my includes referred to `interface` whereas for some reason the folder in Github was `Interface`.

I'd renamed all my folders locally through vscode, but this one hadn't updated git (even though others did :/).

I did the following:

```
cd parser

git mv Interface ifacetemp
git mv ifacetemp interface 

commit...
push...
```

This solved the issue, very annoying.

Comment: Same with you, git ignore my case-sensitive files. set `git config core.ignorecase false` solved or use force push local repo to override remote

Comment: Thanks for this! I discovered that when running tsc from Windows command prompt, imports of other .ts files was not case sensitive. But when running tsc inside a Docker container that's based on Node image, it's case sensitive.